# Explode в Blender как в 3DMax

Tags: 3d, blender

Уже задавал [подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1360403) какое то время назад, но никто не ответил до сих пор. Может быть я не правильно сформулировал...

Мне нужно разделить объект чтоб каждый полигон был отдельным объектом.
В 3dmax есть инструмент Edit mesh -> Explode.
Есть ли такая возможность в блендере?

Хочу сделать это в блендере потому что 3дмакс разделяет все на треугольники
А у меня полигоны из шестиугольников, а соединять их назад в 3дм я не хочу

Comment: Добавлю сюда ссылку для ищущих, на подобный вопрос от  Kurwo Attano, в котором я представил одно из [решений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1360403/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-blender) в виде исполняемого скрипта. Используемая версия blender 2.78

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Входим в режим редактирования меша кнопкой Tab
2. Mesh->Split->FacesByEdge

*Upd: чтобы отдельный полигон вытащить в отдельный объект можно выделить его, а потом нажать Р и выбрать Selection.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так я и делал 8+ тысяч раз ,несколько дней, чтоб разделить эту недофигню на разные объекты, чтоб потом это все конечно же лагало как адская колестница

Comment: Дык оно и будет лагать, если разделить один объект на 8к объектов :)