# Оптимизация клеточной планеты

Tags: unity3d, 3d, blender

Подскажите как лучше сделать? У меня есть такая вот
[сфера-планета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1360403/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B2-blender), у нее каждый шестиугольник отделен в отдельный объект, но таких получилось 10к+. Очевидно что все это дело норм так лагает, хотя планета планировалась еще масштабнее...

Такая же планета есть в игре Rimworld (скриншот) и там этих клеток намного больше и ничего не лагает.

Подскажите как вообще правильно сделать что то подобное, может быть делать каждой клетке отдельный материал или есть какие то другие решения? Потому что разделять на объекты все таки кажется крайне плохой идеей.

Каждой клетке способствует экземпляр класса, возможно не обязательно MonoBehaviour, лишь бы была какая то связь, чтоб можно было выбирать клетку мышкой и получать при этом инфу о ней из ее экземпляра. Порядок нахождения клеток в массивах не важен, только нужно для каждой как то определять соседей. Сейчас это реализовано поиском 6 самых ближайших (Vector3.Distance) клеток, кроме ее самой

Делаю в блендере, юнити
[image: Планета]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должна быть модель данных описывающая клетки икосферы. Позиция, поворот, нормаль, ссылка на соседей. Все это считается кодом и бля этого нужно уметь генерировать икосферу.

Модель клеток должна быть в единственном экземпляре. Один шестиугольник и один пятиугольник что-бы это было легко батчить при рендаринге. Для рендеринга достаточно иметь лишь половину тайлов, перемещая их в позиции видемой стороны сферы, сравнивая скалярное произведение нормали клетки и вектора камеры.

Каждый инстантс материала рендарятся в каждом пасе отдельно, поэтому их должно быть минимальное количество. Если шейдерная программа одна и та-же скажем у земля/трава/песок/скалы, а отличаются лишь текстурой/цветом/другие настройки то используя `Material Property Block` можно обойтись одним материалом который рендарится в один проход.

10k `MonoBehaviour` это недопустимо, они не грузят.

И того от 3 рендер пасов.

Comment: Я попробовал запустить эту сферу со стандартным шейдером на всех клетках, убрал все монобехейворы и вообще все убрал и она все равно лагучая, похоже нужно как то не разделять ее на подобъекты, а орудовать полигонами, но не уверен как это сделать правильно

Comment: Может не по теме, но раз уж тут заговорили об этом... Сфера в блендере поделена на 6-уго. и они считаются там цельными полигонами, но в юнити они разделились на 3-уго.(http://prntscr.com/24o31ur). Все бы хорошо, и треугольники записаны по порядку как надо вроде, то есть по 4 треугольника подряд из одного 6-угольника, потом из следующего... Но так записаны не все и некоторые из них в рандом как то раскиданы.
Вопрос в том, как понимать из каких именно сложен каждый конкретный 6-угольник, чтоб как то это дело структурировать, и если попал в один их них, определять в каком 6-угке и его выделять

Comment: Какая бы ни была фигура в 3d редакторе, в реальности все из треугольников. Кроме 6-ти угольников в и икосфере еще есть 12 5-ти угольников. Блендер в создании сферы участия вообще принимать не должен, иначе там каждый 6-ти и 5-ти угольник это уникальный меш который рендерится в отдельном дроколе и фрейм с тысячами дроколов это невероятные тормоза.

Comment: Эта задача не для начинающего, у вас даже близко нет навыков что-бы делать нечто подобное, не ваш уровень. Вам не по силам ни один из ряда пунктов которые нужно сделать.

Comment: Мне очень лестны ваши слова конечно... Но я привык добиваться целей сколько времени на это не ушло бы, и планирую со всем этим справиться, нужно лишь только определить из каких треугольников сложены какие шестиугольники. Что нибудь придумаю

Comment: Из каких треугольников какие шестиугольники сложены никакой роли не играет, то есть вообще от слова совсем. Шестиугольник есть и есть, остаётся кодом собрать икосферу используя всего один экземпляр меша.

Comment: Я случайно нашел кое что очень мне подходящее, дальше буду двигаться в этом направлении
https://habr.com/ru/post/331738/